# Creating and writing a file with a filename chosen by the user. No error, nothing happens

Tags: python-3.x, file

I wrote a program in Python 3 that's supposed to create a text file with text in it. The user is supposed to enter the file name. No error is shown when I run the code but, sadly, it doesn't work, no file gets created.

The code:

```
print("Enter a name for your file:")
filename = str(input())

file = open(filename, "w")
file.write("File created.")
file.close()
```

I also tried to define the filename in the code itself and it still doesn't create a file:

```
file = open("filename.txt", "w")
file.write("File created.")
file.close()
```

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: Writing "w+" instead of "w" doesn't help.

Comment: @Johan: This question is not a duplicate of that one.

Comment: @FakeCodeMonkeyRashid As far as I've noticed the OP is missing the `+` character after the `w` in the `open` function, which is what the duplicate is about.

Comment: @Johan Writing the + character doesn't help.

Comment: @Johan: The `+` character isn't needed here. If you try the code provided with `python-3.x` it should work exactly as given.

Comment: I see, thanks for the clarification, I'll remove the duplicate flag.

Comment: isn't it some special dir ? like `tmp` in linux where when the file has none of the opened descriptors is auto removed ?

Comment: @Take_Care_ Nothing special, just a desktop folder in Windows 10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, so I googled more and I found out that I was looking for the file in the wrong place. I thought it would show up in the same folder as where I saved the file with the code.

Answer (score 0):

Your code should work exactly as given.

What you have is a permissions issue. Specifically, the script isn't allowed to create a file in the directory in which it resides (if the directory still exists).

Comment: Alright, and how can I change it? I can manually create, move and delete files in the directory in which I have my file with the code.